# Hide username from users list

Tags: wp-admin, columns

I've hidden the username column from users administration with the following code:

```
function modify_user_columns($column) {
    $column = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "username" => __('Username'),
        "name" => __('Name'),
        "email" => "E-mail",
        "birthdate" => "Narozeniny",
        "sleva_moto" => "Sleva moto"


    );
    return $column;
}
add_filter('manage_users_columns','modify_user_columns');
```

The problem is I cannot enter details of any user now, as normally the user detatils are accessed when clicking on the username. Is there a way to add the link to detail page to the `Name` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no direct filters using which we can change the content of Name column. So to get what you want, we should remove 'Name' column too and create our own Name column. Therefore, `modify_user_columns` function will be like this

```
function modify_user_columns($column) {
    $column = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "wdm_name" => __('Name'),
        "email" => "E-mail",
        "birthdate" => "Narozeniny",
        "sleva_moto" => "Sleva moto"


    );
    return $column;
}
```

Now, we have a control on what we can show in the Name column. We can add content in that Name column using filter `manage_users_custom_column`.

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'wdm_display_name_with_edit_link', 10, 3 );

function wdm_display_name_with_edit_link($content, $column_name, $user_object_id){
    if ($column_name == 'wdm_name' && 
        current_user_can( 'edit_user',  $user_object_id) ) {

        //get info of user
        $user_object = get_userdata($user_object_id); 

        //generate edit link
        $edit_link = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'wp_http_referer', urlencode( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ), get_edit_user_link( $user_object->ID ) ) ); 

        //Generate the complete Name with edit link
        $content = "<strong><a href=\"$edit_link\">$user_object->first_name $user_object->last_name</a></strong><br/>"; 
    } else {
        //If logged in user does not have rights 
        //to edit users, just show Name of users
        $content = "<strong>$user_object->first_name $user_object->last_name</strong><br />"; 
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Now it will show Names with Edit link. Hope this helps. :)